# multiple prefix routing in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, routes, project-planning, prefix

I have a new project with 4 users and some tasks which is only allowed to certain users.
Since the users and tasks are fixed i thought no need of using ACL.

is my decision is correct??

Then can i have multiple prefix for each users if yes how can i achive it??

I need to restrict the task of user A from user B how can i achive it???

Comment: i already gone through http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/multiple_admin_levels_in_cakephp/ it helped me a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 users is also a list. I would suggest you to use the [INI-based ACL component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1244/Defining-Permissions-Cake-s-INI-based-ACL) if you don't need to change permissions on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Not especially elegant, but it should get the job done (in each relevant app_controller):

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $currentUser = $this->Auth->user();
    $uName = $currentUser['User']['username'];

    switch($uName){
        case 'User_1':
            $this->Auth->allow('myAction');
    ...
```